# Asogiate won't work on 11.04. How do I fix that?

Tags: 11.04, file-format

Asogiate is a filetype editor (MIME), and on 11.04 if gives an error about the database being malformed, then won't work. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

It turns out that Asogiate was correct, and my database was corrupt. To fix this, I had to remove ~/.local/share/mime/ and then when I ran it again it worked.